# Unity: Game objects in scene load incrementally and not at the same time

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity in my Android app. When the app opens, I show the user data in the Unity scene. User data contains texts and images.

In order to load this data in the scene, I make a lot of 
`UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(GameObject,Function,Params)`
calls to many `C#` scripts in Unity from Android. Each of these calls performs a specific task like loading an image, creating a text, applying the text font etc.

Problem is that the loading of this data right now looks incremental (if that's the right word). So the text is visible first and after a fraction of a second the image shows. Some text effects show later. This looks ugly.

How can I make all the UI elements load at the same time even if it takes some time? Is there a way to freeze the scene before each game object is ready to be drawn so that user sees the final output as it should be and not as a series of UI element loading at different times.

Edit: On Android side, this is a simplified sample of how I make the calls

```
//I call these methods one after the other which make Unity calls
createText(textList)
createImages(imageList)

private fun createText(texts: List<Text>) {
    for (text in texts) {
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Text", "CreateText", text.name+","+text.fontSize+","+text.bold)
    }
}

private fun createImages(images: List<Image>) {
    for (image in images) {
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Image", "CreateImage", image.name+","+image.url+","+image.size)
    }
}
```

On `Unity`, I have the implementations for the same in different C# scripts. Something to note and my bad for not mentioning it is that Images are downloaded from a url which is passed to `Unity` as in the method above. That is what causes this lag in images showing up but I'm fine with that as long as everything else shows up at the same time.

Comment: you could load the sceen as additive, with the camera on a load screen while the items populate and only switch over once done

Comment: Also, you could have the `Renderer` of the gameObjects disabled at first, then enable them all at once (or if appropriate, the whole gameObject `SetActive(false)`). Though maybe there's also something you can do to speed up the long loading time in the first place, or if not feasible, at least improve the perception of it -- e.g. by having the camera zoom into a planet/ universe/ house, show some particles/ swirling/ color animation, having a dramatic music intro, or whatever else is fitting to the theme of your app.

Comment: Both BugFinder and Philipp Lenssen have offered good ideas, essentially hiding all the objects until after they have all been created. But if you are seeing this all accumulating incrementally (that word works for me), that means it is happening over several frames, which kind of surprises me. Can you show us the code that makes the calls to `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage`? I'm curious as to why these happen over multiple frames, if that's what they're doing.

Comment: @StevensMiller Sure, I've added the code above. I am also trying to find out this to know if this can be achieved. Adding an animation or a splash screen does hide the ugly part but it would be great if I could know if it is possible or not in the first place. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks for the suggestion. That is something I have in mind but I wanted to know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible or not because I can apply that in different places in my app. Thanks again!!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Thanks for the suggestion. That is something I have in mind but I wanted to know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible or not because I can apply that in different places in my app. Thanks again!!

Comment: it is semi possible depending on where the info is being fetched from if that cant be relied in to do so in a given time, then it becomes hard to have everything fade in in a regular smooth line.. otherwise yes it can be done